# .NET Core Web API routes and GET request

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following controller (.NET Core Web API application)
(`Source` contains multiple `Site`'s)

**SitesController.cs**

```
// GET: api/sites
[HttpGet]
public IDictionary<int, Site> GetSites() {
    return _db.Sites.ToDictionary(s => s.SiteId, s => s);
}

// GET: api/sites?source=5
[HttpGet("{source}")]
public IDictionary<int, Site> GetSites([FromRoute] int source) {
    return _db.Sites.Where(s => s.SourceId == source).ToDictionary(s => s.SiteId, s => s);
}

// GET: api/sites/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSite([FromRoute] int id) {
```

When the **Angular** client asks `Site`s only from a `Source`, I however get all the sites, the function with the `int source` param is not called... Why?

```
findAllSourceSites(sourceId: number): Observable<Site[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/api/sites`, {
        params: new HttpParams()
            .set('source', sourceId.toString())
    }).pipe(
        map(res => {
            return Object.values(res);
        })
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: is the sourceId empty? please share the url sufix (api/...) which you are calling the api with

Comment: @MarcusHöglund, please see the penleychan's answer comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure it's because of `[FromRoute]` for that to work your URL should be `/api/sites/1`, `HttpParams` is setting the query string which now your URL looks like `/api/sites?source=1`

If you want to use query string you should change your controller to `[FromQuery]`

EDIT:
Due to `AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched.` alternative solution would combine both together.

```
[HttpGet] 
public IDictionary<int, Site> GetSites([FromQuery] int? source) {
    if (source.HasValue) {
        // get specific 
    } else {
        // get all
    }
}
```

Comment: @Serge Ah forgot to mention it should be just `[HttpGet]` now, without `{source}`

Comment: now any breakpoint is hit... `AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

LoggerApi.Controllers.SitesController.GetSites (LoggerApi)
LoggerApi.Controllers.SitesController.GetSites (LoggerApi)`

Comment: It shouldn't though, if it detects that it have a query string, it will use `GetSites(int source)` otherwise `GetSites()`

Comment: Interesting, pretty sure this never was an issue with WebAPI2. Alternative solution you can do `[HttpGet] public IDictionary<int, Site> GetSites([FromQuery] int? source)` and for your logic you would check if `source` contains value do something else get all.

Comment: yes... the last comment was really helpful, and it worked. However I don't really understand why two separate methods does not have the same effect...

Comment: please update your answer with the last comment info, in order I could mark it as answer